# Is this approach idiomatic in ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm new to ReactiveUI, and I'm trying to follow its spirit and its concepts as close as possible. It just came to my mind that I may have misused the `Subscribe` method. Here's my code: it's a viewmodel for a login screen.

```
public class LoginViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public LoginResult LoginResult { [ObservableAsProperty] get; } = LoginResult.Unknown;

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, LoginResult> LoginCommand { get; }

    private readonly IAuthenticationService m_authenticationService = null;
    private readonly INavigationService m_navigationService = null;

    public LoginViewModel(IAuthenticationService i_authenticationService, INavigationService i_navigationService,
        IScheduler i_mainThreadScheduler = null, IScheduler i_currentThreadScheduler = null)
        : base(i_mainThreadScheduler, i_currentThreadScheduler)
    {
        m_authenticationService = i_authenticationService;
        m_navigationService = i_navigationService;

        IObservable<bool> canLogin = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.Username, vm => vm.Password,
                (username, password) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            .DistinctUntilChanged();

        LoginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(Login, canLogin, null);
        LoginCommand.ToPropertyEx(this, vm => vm.LoginResult, scheduler: null);

        // This is where I'm not sure
        LoginCommand.Subscribe(lr => 
            {
                if (lr == LoginResult.Success)
                {
                    m_navigationService.NavigateToViewModel<HomeViewModel>();
                }
            });
    }

    private async Task<LoginResult> Login()
    {
        return await m_authenticationService.LogUserInAsync(Username, Password);
    }
```

(I've defined a navigation service because I'm going to work with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, so I'm using view-first navigation, which whill be implemented in platform-specific classes. Anyway, the important part is that, if the login is successful, I want to do something (go to the home screen).)

I wonder whether the `Subscribe` I've called on the result of `LoginCommand` is the idiomatic way. I should probably have implemented that part in the `Login` method itself. On the other hand, I like to separate the login proper and its outcome from "what to do next", and `Subscribe` seems to be exactly that: "what to do after the command is completed".

Is my code correct? Or is that `Subscribe` a code smell, and I should do things differently?

Comment: You could do a WhenAnyValue on the property you set as well is the other approach you could take. It's a little unusual to have both subscribe and a property

Comment: @GlennWatson I tried that, too. However, the handler is called only when the value changes. If I cause a login error, then another one, the second time the handler is not run. This is not ideal, for example if I wanted to play an animation on the error message. Is there a way to trigger `WhenAnyValue` also when the property is set to its current value?

Comment: Yeah WhenAnyValue will only notify if the new value is different to the previous one eg distinct.  I think the subscribe is acceptable in your scenario tbh. It's implying you want the result of the command.